# Javascript - Add Variables in Jquery Command

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 function bookRemoved(bookId)
     {
         alert(bookId) ;
         $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.className').hide(1000); // Want it Here

      } );}
```

In Above example, the bookId returns class Name. How can I use it as class name to hide it as shown in above example.

I would like something like this:

```
     $('.bookId').hide(1000); // Want it Here
```

bookId should return its value. Suppose if bookId has 23, it should look like this.
        $('.23').hide(1000); // Want it Here

PS: I am new to Javascript and Jquery

Comment: Btw, class names aren't supposed to start with a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like

```
function bookRemoved(bookId)
{
     alert(bookId) ;
     $('.' + bookId).hide(1000); // Want it Here

}
```

We dont need DOM ready there,in the defined function.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a means of passing the argument of one function as argument to another. Variables can be passed into functions, `$` is just a function, within the `(...)` sequence following a function reference.

```
function bookRemoved(bookId) {
    alert(bookId);
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.'+bookId).hide(1000);
    });
};
```

In this case:

- the function `alert` is fired on the variable `bookId`
- the function `$` is fired on the `document` variable.
- the method `ready` is accessed from the returned object of `$(document)`
- `ready` is fired with a function, an anonymous function (i.e., without a name)
- the function `$` is fired on a string concatenation between `.` and `bookId`
- the `hide` method is then accessed and fired with `1000`

Hopefully this better explains the general terminology and what it is that is occurring within the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
function bookRemoved(bookId) {
    alert(bookId);
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.' + bookId).hide(1000);
    });
}
```

Do you mean this?

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner approach. Seperate your document.ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    function bookRemoved(bookId) {
        $(bookId).hide(1000);  
    }

    //pass in your specified class name OR id as the argument.
    bookRemoved('.someClasssName'); 

});
```

More info on hide method here: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.' + bookId).hide(1000);
```

In javascript `+` operator is used to...

1. add nembers.
2. concatenate strings if one of the operand is string.

for example...

`1 + 2 == 3`

`"abc" + "xyz" == "abcxyz"` and

`"1" + 2 == "12" // "1" here is a string`